# how to handle upvote concurrency in dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, concurrency, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have post_id as hash key and upvote as attribute, I want to handle concurrency while making a upvote and undoing that upvote. I want to process every upvote weather it's making an upvote or removing that upvote.

In frontend we will be showing only upvote button. clicking one time makes an upvote, clicking another time undo that upvote.

for example the post has initially 0 upvote, when user upvote increase upvote to +1, when same user upvote click that upvote button one more time, undo that upvote. how can I handle concurrently in dynamodb?

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB handles concurrency natively, all writes to an item are strongly serialized and are executed by the order they are received by DynamoDB.

If strict counting is required, you may need to introduce one of the patterns discussed in this [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/implement-resource-counters-with-amazon-dynamodb/)